# changing widgetactivedisplaymode iOS

Tags: ios

I have widget for my main application. Which I need to change activedisplaymode. Apple has not exposed any API for these. Can it be achievable in any other way. I am supporting it only for iOS 10.0 and above only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set in your **viewDidLoad** method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
}
```

and later when you want to make changes to size you can do it in **widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange**

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
    else {
        // when its in expanded mode
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: yourHeight)

    }
}
```

*width is fixed. So you can pass 0*

Comment: What if widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode is set again to expanded mode, after activecurrentdisplaymode is in compact mode.

Comment: Compact mode has it's own fixed. So whatever size you give it will be over ridden. So setting widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode will not have any effect.

Comment: setting widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode in the viewDidLoad is a flag to OS what we would like to Use the maximum defined size for expanded mode. Later we can reduce it's size on widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange method when activeDisplayMode is in Expanded state